# Convert my Next.js web-Application to Android App

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, html-lists, next.js

> I am new to react and make my on website through react and next.js and
>   now i want to make a mobile app for this using the same code. so
>   please give me a suggestions that how i can convert my web-app to
>   android-app without changing much in my code.

Comment: What do you mean by "call a class" and "call my className"?

Comment: Yeah, I like NextJS too for making web apps, but unfortunately it doesn't seem doable to make actual mobile apps, not just PWAs, with NextJS. I've tried doing so with Cordova and with Capacitor, but there are too many issues to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to understand is that mobile app created from website tech are different from the native android or ios app.

We still can bundle our web app to become hybrid mobile app by adding more stack like:

- Progressive Web App from Google (the easiest way, but distributed without playstore or istore)
- Ionic Framework (both works for Android and iOS)
- Adobe Phonegap (both works for Android and iOS)

You can try to find other similar stacks.